# C# Multi threaded Server

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, server

I have this client and server code.
Client:

```
namespace ClientTest
{
internal class Program
{
private static TcpClient client;
private static NetworkStream stream;
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
string temp;
client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2",5052);
stream = client.GetStream();
Console.WriteLine(client.SendBufferSize);
while ((temp = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
{
Send(temp);
}

Thread one=new Thread(()=> SendFile(new FileInfo(@"1.doc")));
one.Start();
Thread two=new Thread(()=> SendFile(new FileInfo(@"2.docx")));
two.Start();
// Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static void SendFile(FileInfo file)
{
stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1);
byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(file.Length);
byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Name);
byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)fileName.Length);
byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + fileName.Length];

id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
size.CopyTo(fileInfo, 2);
fileNameLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
fileName.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length); //Размер файла, имя

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
int count;

long sended = 0;

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
sended += count;
Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sended.", sended);
}
stream.Flush();
}

private static void Send(string message)
{
byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)0);
 byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
 byte[] msgLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)msg.Length);
 byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + msg.Length];

 id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
 msgLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
 msg.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);
 stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length);
 stream.Flush();

}
}
}
```

Server:

```
namespace Server_Test
{
class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server serv = new Server();
    }
    private TcpListener listener { get; set; }
    private NetworkStream stream { get; set; }

    public Server()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 5052);
        listener.Start();
        new Thread(ListenForClients).Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = this.listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            new Thread(HandleClient).Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClient(object tcpClient)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        while (client.Connected)
        {

            Recieve(client);
        }
    }

    private void Recieve(TcpClient client)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 12);
            if (bytesRead == 0) return;

            ushort id = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
            long len = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 2);
            ushort nameLen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 10);
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, nameLen);
            string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, nameLen);

            if (id == 1)
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new     FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    int recieved = 0;
                    while (recieved < len)
                    {
                        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                        recieved += bytesRead;
                        writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes recieved.", recieved);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File length: {0}", len);
                Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", fileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem:i can't send 2 files in threads. If i send 1 file, server receives it and correctly saves.
What changes needed in this code to let client transfer 2 or more files and to let server receive it? 
UDP. Added modified SendFile, but in doesn't work.

```
public static void SendFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        TcpClient client;
        NetworkStream stream;
        client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2", 5052);
        stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1);
        byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(file.Length);
        byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Name);
        byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)fileName.Length);
        byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + fileName.Length];

        id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
        size.CopyTo(fileInfo, 2);
        fileNameLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
        fileName.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

        stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length); //Размер файла, имя

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
        int count;

        long sended = 0;

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
            while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                sended += count;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sended.", sended);
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can't send on one stream two different files simultaneously. Either you need to make 2 connections or send the files sequentially.

Comment: So, what changes i need to make in this code?

Comment: The `SendFile` method should be creating the `TcpClient`, not the `Main` method. Each send method needs to have its own connection.

Comment: OK, thank you, and on server side it should work?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the server side not working but thats just a cursory read.

Comment: And it can be same ports in this connections(5052, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, your two separate sending threads cannot share the same instance of `client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2",5052);` to simultaneously send data. Each thread should have its own instance. Note, however, that it is fine for 2 client sockets to hit the same server-side IP:port simultaneously. It is just that the outbound port on the client-side has to be different between the 2 connections. When you create an additional outbound TCP connection on the client, the `TcpClient` will automatically use the next available outbound port.

For example, you could try something like the following:

```
internal class Program
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SenderThreadClass stc1 = SenderThreadClass("192.168.1.2", 5052);
    SenderThreadClass stc2 = SenderThreadClass("192.168.1.2", 5052);
    Thread one = new Thread(()=> stc1.SendFile(new FileInfo(@"1.doc")));
    one.Start();
    Thread two = new Thread(()=> stc2.SendFile(new FileInfo(@"2.docx")));
    two.Start();
}
}

public class SenderThreadClass
{
private TcpClient client;
private NetworkStream stream;

public SenderThreadClass(string serverIP, int serverPort)
{
   client = new TcpClient(serverIP, serverPort);
   stream = client.GetStream();
}

public void SendFile(FileInfo file)
{
byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1);
byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(file.Length);
byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Name);
byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)fileName.Length);
byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + fileName.Length];

id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
size.CopyTo(fileInfo, 2);
fileNameLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
fileName.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length); //Размер файла, имя

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
int count;
long sended = 0;

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
sended += count;
Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sended.", sended);
}
stream.Flush();
}
}
```

Comment: I just produced some sample code. This is not compile-checked code because I don't have the IDE in front of me, but it should give you the right idea on how to proceed.

Comment: I've tried, but in doesn't work. Do you know possible reasons?

Comment: On the server side, the `private NetworkStream stream { get; set; }` member should be removed and instead instantiated inside the `private void Recieve(TcpClient client) { }` function as a local variable. For example, you can add a new first line to that function as: `NetworkStream stream;`

Comment: OK, i did it, but should i write next stream=client.getstream()?

Comment: It looks like that statement happens as the first line inside the `try { }` block, so there is no need to do it twice.

Comment: But in catch i have stream.close(), so if it's in try block, it doesn't work.

Comment: Move the `stream.Close();` and `client.Close();` lines out of the `catch { }` block and into the `finally { }` block. Put them after the `.flush()` call.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please remember to accept the answer.